# Drupal 9 - drupalTranslations is not defined

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-9

I'm an Angular front end dev, I work with a team that uses Drupal for content.

The scenario is that we use the Drupal.t() method to translate the strings.

When I translate the word from the back-office, it works!, but I can't see the change on my page. So I tested it with another laptop from a colleague, and it works!

My colleague has a function in his browser which is "drupalTranslations", it gives him the translated strings.

When I run this function in my browser, it doesn't work, it gives me "drupalTranslations is not defined" while "Drupal" and "drupalSettings" work!

[image: Error Message]

Do I have to install something?

FYI: We run the project with Docker ( Drupal 9.x ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/localization-api/translating-strings-in-javascript?

Comment: A few things that you need to clarify.. Are the working and non working machines both viewing the same Drupal page? Both logged in or 1 logged in and 1 not logged in?

Comment: Does doing a cache clear via drush fix it? `drush cr`

Comment: @BaldeBinos Yes, I checked it... Drupal.t() is working for me.. The problem is that when I want to check the translated word in the webpage, there's just the original word

Comment: @2pha Yeah, I tested with the same page... We have the same environment.. I did "drush cr" "drush cim -y" ... All these stuffs but still not works.

Comment: where you both logged in as the same user? different users?

Comment: @2pha Same user, configuration... same in everything

Comment: If it truly is the same user and same page Drupal will be serving the same stuff, only thing left I can think of is browser cache, use devtools to make sure you are both loading from the server and not browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to replicate the issue on Drupal 9 with a simple javscript file

```
console.log(Drupal.t('Comments'))
console.log(Drupal.drupalTranslations('Comments'))

コメント
TypeError: Drupal.drupalTranslations is not a function
```

There appears to be an open issue ([Text in Drupal.t() on some pages is not translated after installing a module [library cache problem]](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2972582)) related to this marked active but without progress since 2018. The issue relates to a caching bug.

I also found [drupal-8-react-i18n-and-typescript](https://medium.com/swissquote-engineering/drupal-8-react-i18n-and-typescript-c43aab12532d) which might help you along, but if you're using the same code as your colleague, I'm inclined to thing it is the cache bug.

Comment: I have found that the function _locale_rebuild_js() is supposed to create a JavaScript file containing the drupalTranslations variable. How can I add this function ?